# how can my In-App-Purchase cater for volume purchase program?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My customer wants to purchase my 2 In-App-Purchase products within one of my App on 16 ipads that her School District owns. However, due to their volume purchase program they cannot purchase them as in-app purchases. They want us to create a paid app for these contests so that they can purchase them. Is there any other way for both of us to adopt instead of creating a paid app for them separately?

Answer (score 1):

I am a volume purchaser and have just run into this problem myself.  As far as I can tell from my research the only way around this issue is for the developer to create a paid for 'FULL Version' that contains all the features of the in-app purchases.

If anyone comes up with a better way please do share!